# Reload bash script from .bash_profile when switching git branches

Tags: git, bash, sed, alias

I got tired of hunting down Jira tickets for whatever story branch (Git) I'm on, so I made this little script and put it in my `.bash_profile`.

`alias ojt="open https://mycompanyname.atlassian.net/browse/MARMO-"$(git symbolic-ref HEAD | sed s/[^0-9]*//g)""`

Works fine until I switch branches:
`git checkout 1234`

After switching branches and I use the `ojt` alias command, it opens the Jira ticket from the *previous branch I was on*.

If I reload `source ~/.bash_profile`, it works. I don't want to reload the whole profile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
alias ojt="open https://mycompanyname.atlassian.net/browse/MARMO-"'$(git symbolic-ref HEAD | sed s/[^0-9]*//g)'
```

If you put the subshell (`$(...)`) in double quotes or without surrounding quotes, it will be evaluated immediately (i.e. whenever you source your `.bash_profile`).  If you enclose it in single quotes, it will be evaluated lazily (i.e. whenever you call the alias).

Actually, since you don't need any other values to be expanded immediately, you should be able to just put the whole thing in single quotes:

```
alias ojt='open https://mycompanyname.atlassian.net/browse/MARMO-$(git symbolic-ref HEAD | sed s/[^0-9]*//g)'
```

Notice that if you are mixing expanded and lazy values, you must concatenate the strings with different quotes for this to work; if you just nest them, you will get extra quote characters in your string, and the outer-most set of quotes will be used to determine whether to expand variables and subshells or not.

Example:

```
VAR=abc
echo "$VAR $VAR"     # abc abc
echo '$VAR $VAR'     # $VAR $VAR 
echo "$VAR '$VAR'"   # abc 'abc'
echo '$VAR "$VAR"'   # $VAR "$VAR"
echo "$VAR "'$VAR'   # abc $VAR
```

Comment: that did the trick! Thanks for teaching me something new. Cheers.